# ZF2 + Doctrine 2 + SOAP

Tags: web-services, soap, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 applications, Intranet and Extranet.
The Extranet app does not communicate directly with database, only with web service. The Intranet app is normal with database.

I need use SOAP for communicate with my database, so I have
View -> Controller -> Service -> Entity.

For communicate with service I am using:

[Controller]

```
$client = new Client("my_soap_address");
$user = $client->test();
```

[Service]

```
public function test()
{
   $res = $this->em->getRepository("my_entity")->fetchPairs();
   return $res;
}
```

Without SOAP, works perfectly!
With SOAP, returns this error:

```
Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object
```

If my service returns a string, integer or boolean as:

[Service]

```
public function test()
{
   return "is OK";
}
```

My SOAP works normally.

The problem is any method as getRepository(), getReference(), etc.. But I need these methods for get or put informations from my database.

Please, can anybody help with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

ps.: I have a controller with handleWSDL and handleSOAP between Controler and service.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem!
I need send the EntityManager with Soap for the service works.

Let's go:

In my SoapController:

```
use Path\of\my\service as MyService;

public function handleSOAP($class, $url) {
    $soap = new Server($url."?wsdl");
    $soap->setClass($class);
    $soap->setObject(new MyService($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')));
    $soap->handle();
}
```

For works, I need instance inside setObject Method, my service as I instanced on my Module.php file inside of getServiceConfig().

So, now is ok!

Thanks!